# Though I uninstalled the apache2 in my ubuntu 20.04 Azure VM, apache2 -v command giving me the current installed version

Tags: server, apache2, nginx, putty, azure

I have the Azure VM is of Linux (Ubuntu) -20.04.

Long back, installed the apache2 (version is 2.4.41). Now I have tried to uninstall apache2, nginx but when I enter apache2 -v command in the azure vm (putty) - it is still showing me the current version of that server.
Why?

I already uninstalled right but why it is showing me?

[image]

Comment: You have to check if Apache was probably installed a different way, outside the package system.
What is the output of  `which apache2`?

Comment: `/usr/sbin/apache2` is the output of `which apache2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably used something like `sudo apt remove apache2` but according to `dpkg -S /usr/sbin/apache2`, the `/usr/sbin/apache2` file is provided by the `apache2-bin` package.

Sure enough, `dpkg -L apache2` shows that this file is not included in the `apache2` package.

Run `dpkg -l | grep apache` to list all packages that contain `apache` in the name and/or the description.

Uninstall all packages listed that are associated with apache2, like `apache2-bin` for example.

- `dpkg -S /usr/sbin/apache2` lists the package that provides the specified file.
- `dpkg -L apache2` lists all files provided by the specified package.
- `dpkg -l` lists all installed packages
- `dpkg -l | grep apache` pipes the output to `grep` to filter and show only results that contain "apache".

Comment: Hope your answer also may work. I got the solution from the Stack Overflow user @[Imran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18229970/imran) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77565794/22054564

Comment: Yes, the `sudo apt autoremove` command should remove it if `apache2-bin` was never explicitly installed and/or there are also no currently installed packages that depend on `apache2-bin`.